# Migrate database from Heroku to AWS

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-web-services

I want to migrate our postgres db from heroku to our own postgres on AWS.

I have tried using pg_dump and pg_restore to do the migration and it works; but it takes a really long time to do this. Our database size is around 20GB.

What's the best way to do the migration with minimal downtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you mean AWS RDS PostgreSQL:

`pg_dump` and `pg_restore`

I know you don't like it, but you don't really have other options. With a lot of hoop jumping you might be able to do it with Londiste or Slony-I  on a nearby EC2 instance, but it'd be ... interesting. That's not the most friendly way to do an upgrade, to say the least.

What you should be able to do is ship WAL into RDS PostgreSQL, and/or stream replication logs. However [Amazon don't support this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61305/get-wal-files-from-aws-rds-postgresql-instance).

Hopefully Amazon will adopt some part of 9.4's logical replication and logical changeset extraction features, or better yet the [BDR project](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) - but I wouldn't hold my breath.

### If you mean AWS EC2

If you're running your own EC2 instance with Pg, use [replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) then promote the standby into the new master.

Comment: I asked heroku support, and they said they don't support a slave db outside of heroku. Have you done that before?

Comment: Ah, I missed the Heroku part. You can still probably make Slony or Londiste work but streaming replication you are out of luck.